# Wrong width when using ControlBox to resize window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl within a WinForms-form where within is a panel that resizes its content by custom code when the parent window is resized:

```
private void ResizeElements(FlowLayoutPanel panel) {
  panel.SuspendLayout();
  foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls) {
    ctrl.Width = panel.ClientSize.Width - 20;
  }
  panel.ResumeLayout();
}

private void flowPanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ResizeElements((FlowLayoutPanel)sender);
}
```

**This works** just fine when I resize the window manually by grabbing it at the lower right corner and resize there:

[image]

This **does not work** however, wenn I maximize the window and after that click onto the restore-controlbox between minimize and maximize.

The controls from that Panel seem to have the right width, but the FlowLayoutPanel that contains them has a horizontal scrollbar:

[image][image]

When I resize the window manually again the horizontal scrollbar disappears and everything is as expected.

The flowpanel has DockingStyle.Fill

Update: I currently do the following to get around this issue:

```
private void frmMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var oldWindowState = _previousWindowState;
            _previousWindowState = this.WindowState;
            if (oldWindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized && this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.Width++;
                this.Width--;
            }
        }
```

So I resize manually when detecting a restore-click forcing the correct events to be fired. **I am fully aware** that this is an evil hack and still would prefer a more clean solution.

(Update): Parent Controls:

```
WinForm
  ->Panel Dock: Fill, AutoSize: false
     ->UserControl Dock: Fill, AutoSize: false
        ->TabControl Dock: Fill
           ->Tab 
              ->FlowLayoutPanel Dock: Fill, AutoSize: false
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Anchor` and `Dock` properties?

Comment: @RezaAghaei The controls within the flowControl are userControls that have some "specialities" (like incompatible docking-settings) that do not allow that

Comment: Might have been with a DockPanel as parent. But just not with a FlowLayoutPanel (which I need)

Comment: Use a `TableLayoutPanel` having a single column and add auto-sized rows dynamically.

Comment: SO users never post enough code when they have an automatic layout problem, the inevitable screenshot never helps.  Well, the panel did not resize itself, even though you selected DockStyle.Fill.  Tends to be caused by conflicting layout instructions, like the container of the panel also using auto-sizing.  That makes layout bi-stable, swapping back-and-forth between two solutions.

Comment: IMHO it isn't easy (if not impossible) to grab ALL the possibly relevant parts in a WinForm-Project without "spamming" with too much source. The container of the Panel is a TabPage (no AutoSize-Property). The TabControl from that is DockStyle:Fill. The Usercontrol that contains the TabControl has no AutoSize and is inserted with DockStyle.Fill. Then itself in a panel that has dockStyle.Fill and no AutoSize directly in the WinForm.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I might give a try. Currently it looks, however, that the TableLayout has problems with items that have elements with heights changing programmatically (I have to resize the height of a textbox by its content, which cannot be done through autoSize or dock)

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I still do the "evil" solution. Seems to work just fine,.

Comment: Using resize event? Surely you can make it work, but it's somehow dirty and hard to maintain. But you are the one who should be satisfied with result :) My solution for such problem would be `TableLayoutPanel`.